# Assign output of solve to variables

Tags: replacement, variable-definitions, assignment

I have this input:

```
Solve[x^2 + 3 x + 2 == 0, x]
```

which gives this output:

```
{{x -> -2}, {x -> -1}}
```

I want the first x to be named `x1` and the second x to be named `x2` without having to copy the value and doing `x1=-2` manually and `x2=-1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
{x1, x2} = x /. Solve[x^2 + 3 x + 2 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {-2, -1}
> ```

Comment: loved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
{x1, x2} = Last @@@ Solve[x^2 + 3 x + 2 == 0, x]
(* {-2, -1} *)
```

or

```
{x1, x2} = Solve[x^2 + 3 x + 2 == 0, x][[All,1,-1]]
(* {-2, -1} *)
```

or

```
sol = Solve[x^2 + 3 x + 2 == 0, x];
sol[[All, 0]] = Last;
{x1, x2} = sol 
(* {-2, -1} *)
```

Note: Since this question has a much simpler structure than the question linked by Artes, these tricks work for the current case (with a single-variable expression to be solved), but not for the more general case in the linked Q/A.

Comment: Can't you see it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Artes, -- now that i saw your comment -- yes.

Answer (score 2):

A certain generalization using an indexed variable:

```
r = FindInstance[Sin[x] == Cos[x] && -10 < x < 10, x, Reals, 15] // Values // Flatten // N
```

> {-5.49779, 7.06858, 0.785398, -8.63938, 3.92699, -2.35619}

```
Map[(x[#] = r[[#]]) &, Range @ Length @ r];

{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}
```

> {-5.49779, 7.06858, 0.785398, -8.63938, 3.92699, -2.35619}