# Simple pick up an element from above line

Tags: data

( Did not readily find from Documentation even if used before).

```
NSolve[ 2 x^3 + x ^2 - 5 x + 2 == 0, x]
```

How to collect roots with new labels a,b and c?

Comment: `Thread[{a, b, c} -> (x /. sol)]` or `Thread[{a, b, c} -> Last @@@ sol]`?

Comment: Have a look [Assign output of solve to variables](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60135/assign-output-of-solve-to-variables?lq=1).

Comment: @BobHanlon, @Community, inferring from the accepted answer, the OP wants to  turn `{{x -> -2.}, {x -> 0.5}, {x -> 1.}}` into `{{a -> -2.}, {b -> 0.5}, {c -> 1.}}` .  None of the answers in the linked q/a does that. So I suggest this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Trying to put into proper perspective . The output of NSolve is  to be collected under new preferred labels. Even the x's can be renamed once isolated. Need not read  more into my accepted answer. As OP I requested merely for plain assignment, forgotten stuff  reminder as stated.However kguler supplies much more useful content ( yet to run it fully) serving more to herd data under a new label.When duplicated info serves my purpose, I cannot be as OP  be indifferent to new detail and I can get back here anytime under old questions reference anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol = NSolve[2 x^3 + x^2 - 5 x + 2 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> -2.}, {x -> 0.5}, {x -> 1.}} *)
```

Judging from OP's acceptance of this answer, the task is turn `sol` into

```
{{a -> -2.}, {b -> 0.5}, {c -> 1.}}
```

Here are a few methods, sorted by `StringCount`, to relabel `x`

```
new = {a, b, c};
List /@ Thread[new -> (x /. sol)]
List /@ Thread[new -> Last @@@ sol]
Block[{i = 1}, sol /. x :> new[[i++]]]
List /@ Thread[new -> sol[[All, 1, 2]]]
List /@ MapThread[Rule, {new, x /. sol}]
Block[{i = 1}, sol /. Thread[x :> new[[i++]]]]
Block[{sol2 = sol}, sol2[[All, 1, 1]] = new; sol2]
Block[{i = 1}, sol /. Rule[x, y_] :> Rule[new[[i++]], y]]
Block[{nl = Reverse@new}, sol /. x :> First[nl = RotateRight[nl]]]
Block[{nl = Reverse@new}, Replace[sol, x :> First[nl = RotateRight[nl]], 3]]
Block[{nl = Reverse@new}, MapAt[First[nl = RotateRight[nl]] &, sol, {{All, 1, 1}}]]
Block[{nl = Reverse@new},ReplacePart[sol, {_, 1, 1} :> First[nl = RotateRight[nl]]]]
```

all give

```
(* {{a -> -2.}, {b -> 0.5}, {c -> 1.}} *)
```